# Check if function is empty in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have some callback that has a parameter defined like this:

`val getMoreFunction : (() -> FSDirResult)? = null`

Nullable, because I need to know if the function is actually defined. But I feel it's bad. I'd rather pass `{}` instead of `null` to my callbacks. So is there a way to determine if empty function was passed?

Comment: Why can't you just call an empty function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally you would have a default parameter that can be called i.e.:

```
fun saneDefault(getMoreFunction: (() -> String) = { "" }): Boolean {
    val result = getMoreFunction()
    return result.isEmpty()
}
```

However if you *really, really, really* need to know if the argument was passed you can store the default parameter value like so:

```
private val DEFAULT = { throw UnsupportedOperationException("this shouldn't be called") }

fun isDefaultPassed(getMoreFunction: (() -> String) = DEFAULT): Boolean {
    if(getMoreFunction == DEFAULT){
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: You can even compare references using `===`

Comment: Heh, a good one. I really thought that there's a clean way to do it, but I guess, your might be the only one...

Comment: This is the typical way, you pass in an empty default function that does default behavior and just call it anyway (since it'll do nothing), or you check its `===` reference to not do anything.  This is "the clean" way in Kotlin.